# MySQL Smart Ordering the Results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query which returns the related data of given information based on `title` relevancy and `title,description,tags` relevancy.

The problem is, when I do specific searches for episode lists, `relevance` and `title_relevance` is having the same ratio. If they are all the same I want to order the result based on the episode number.

Example query;

```
SELECT   `test_vids`.id , 
         `test_vids`.title, 
         test_vids.tags, 
         MATCH (title,description,tags) against ('Vikingler 1. Bölüm,Vikingler,Bölüm,vikingler vicky' IN boolean mode) AS relevance,
         MATCH (title) against ('Vikingler 1. Bölüm,Vikingler,Bölüm,vikingler vicky'      IN boolean mode) AS title_relevance
FROM     `test_vids` 
WHERE    MATCH (title,description,tags) against('Vikingler 1. Bölüm,Vikingler,Bölüm,vikingler vicky' IN boolean mode)
AND      `test_vids`.pub > 0 
ORDER BY title_relevance DESC, 
         relevance DESC, 
         cast(title AS UNSIGNED) DESC 
LIMIT    0, 20
```

Example Result;

```
id     |  title                                        | tags                    | relevance          | title_relevance   |
XXXXXX | Flori Mumajesi Karma Ft Bruno Klajdi Dj Vicky | yabanci,pop,müzik,dinle | 15.147967338562012 | 21.81067657470703   ##WTF IS THIS???
XXXXXX | Vikingler 4. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 3. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 6. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 8. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 10. Bölüm                           | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 5. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 1. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 7. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 9. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 2. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
```

Expected Result;

```
id     |  title                                        | tags                    | relevance          | title_relevance   |
XXXXXX | Vikingler 1. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 2. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 3. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 4. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 5. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 6. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 7. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 8. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 9. Bölüm                            | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
XXXXXX | Vikingler 10. Bölüm                           | vikingler vicky         | 31.47698974609375  | 6.191696643829346
```

How can I order this correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to strip the number from the titles and `order by stripped_title, number`. But what if you find titles like `'Viking Sezon 3 Bölüm 2'` (season 3 episode 2)? Then you'd have to get *two* numbers and `order by stripped_title, first_number, second_number`. And for titles like `'Viking Bölüm 2 Sezon 3'` you'd have to `order by stripped_title, second_number, first_number`. You see, that this takes more than just simple string manipulation and shows a flaw in your data model: for series you should have separate columns for series title, season and episode.

Answer (score 0):

Add `CONVERT(REPLACE(RIGHT(LEFT(title ,12) ,3),'.',''), UNSIGNED INTEGER)` to your `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT   `test_vids`.id , 
         `test_vids`.title, 
         test_vids.tags, 
         MATCH (title,description,tags) against ('Vikingler 1. Bölüm,Vikingler,Bölüm,vikingler vicky' IN boolean mode) AS relevance,
         MATCH (title) against ('Vikingler 1. Bölüm,Vikingler,Bölüm,vikingler vicky'      IN boolean mode) AS title_relevance
FROM     `test_vids` 
WHERE    MATCH (title,description,tags) against('Vikingler 1. Bölüm,Vikingler,Bölüm,vikingler vicky' IN boolean mode)
AND      `test_vids`.pub > 0 
ORDER BY CONVERT(REPLACE(RIGHT(LEFT(title ,12) ,3),'.',''), UNSIGNED INTEGER)
         title_relevance DESC, 
         relevance DESC, 
         cast(title AS UNSIGNED) DESC 
LIMIT    0, 20
```

Small Example:

Input

```
Vikingler 4. Bölüm
Vikingler 3. Bölüm
Vikingler 6. Bölüm
Vikingler 8. Bölüm
Vikingler 10. Bölüm
Vikingler 5. Bölüm
Vikingler 1. Bölüm
Vikingler 7. Bölüm
Vikingler 9. Bölüm
Vikingler 2. Bölüm
```

Code

```
SELECT title
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY CONVERT(REPLACE(RIGHT(LEFT(title ,12) ,3),'.',''), UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

Output

```
title
Vikingler 1. Bölüm
Vikingler 2. Bölüm
Vikingler 3. Bölüm
Vikingler 4. Bölüm
Vikingler 5. Bölüm
Vikingler 6. Bölüm
Vikingler 7. Bölüm
Vikingler 8. Bölüm
Vikingler 9. Bölüm
Vikingler 10. Bölüm
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c74bd/24/0

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer and reminding me the usage of regex. But unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. when I use title `REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' ASC` I get the following result; `4,1,7,9,2,5,6,8,10`

Comment: try now, i have changed my approach as long as the title column is the same?

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the approach, i really appreciate. The thing is I will have lots of different titles such as these examples; `XXX Season 1 Episode 8, XXX S01E05, XXX Ep6, XXX Ep 7` etc. Is it possible to make an approach for dynamic content?

Comment: yes, you would need to create a function and then call it in the order by